ASCX inheritence
I have a User Control in CheckBoxList.ascx:
<%@ Control Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="CheckBoxList" Codebehind="CheckBoxList.ascx.cs" %>
<% ... (lots of elements %>

And a code-behind CheckBoxList.ascx.cs
public partial class CheckBoxList: UserControl
{
  // Some methods
}

I need to add features in CheckBoxList, but, as it is used in a lots of place, I would like to create a new specific class which inherits of CheckBoxList.
public partial class MyCustomCBList : CheckBoxList
{
  public void DoCustomStuff() {
    // lblTitle is in CheckBoxList.ascx
    lblTitle.Text = "Some new stuffs";
  }
}

How can I do this without having to modify heavily CheckBoxList or to copy-paste a lots of code?

You have not made heavily modification or copy-pasted a lot of code now, have you?

@shingo sorry I don't understand your question. I did nothing yet, I can't make it work, because I don't know how.
